# How to redirect to specific path with .htacces?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Im writing Redirect Rule and came up on a problem that could interest some of you.

The idea is to redirect old path `voyage/grece/mykonos/` to new path `voyage/cyclades/mykonos/`

But whatever i tried failed and redirect me to strange url :/ ->

`http://www.agencedevoyage.com/voyage/europe/cyclades/mykonos/?continent=europe&country=grece&town=mykonos&type=voyage`

Does that mean the php traitement is done without refreshing the page or something like that ? How can I avoid this ?

### Rules I tried :

```
ReWriteRule \/voyage\/europe\/grece\/mykonos\/  http://www.agencedevoyage.com/voyage/europe/cyclades/mykonos/ [R=301,L]

RedirectPermanent /voyage/europe/grece/mykonos/ http://www.agencedevoyage.com/voyage/europe/cyclades/mykonos/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^/voyage/europe/grece/mykonos/$ http://www.agencedevoyage.com/voyage/europe/cyclades/mykonos/ [R=301,L]
```

Or

```
Redirect 301 /voyage/europe/grece/mykonos/   http://www.agencedevoyage.com/voyage/europe/cyclades/mykonos/
```

Make sure that the opening of the .htaccess file contains the 2 lines of code below which enables the Apache module to rewrite the URLS, then place your redirections below them

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Nup none of those working it still redirect me to strange url. It's as if the redirection was not affecting the page...